# select(String str) method at Play2.2.1

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using play2.2.1.
And I'm not sure of the meaning of select method.
I don't know how much I show my code to get a correct answer. So, I will show a whole code, but I want to know the role of the select method.  Maybe, just seeing add() is okay.

This is controller.

```
//Action for making a message
    public static Result add() {
        Form<Message> f = new Form(Message.class);
        List<Member> mems = Member.find.select("name").findList();
        return ok(add.render("fill-in form", f, mems));
    }

    //Action correponding to create a message
    public static Result create() {
        Form<Message> f = new Form(Message.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(!(f.hasErrors())) {
            Message data = f.get();
            data.member = Member.findByName(data.name);
            data.save();
            return redirect("/");
        } else {
            return redirect("/");
        }
    }

    //Action to register member
    public static Result add2() {
        Form<Member> f = new Form(Member.class);
        return ok(add2.render("member registration form", f));
    }

    //Action to create member
    public static Result create2() {
        Form<Member> f = new Form(Member.class).bindFromRequest();
        if(!(f.hasErrors())) {
            Member data = f.get();
            data.save();
            return redirect("/");
        } else {
            return ok(add2.render("Error", f));
        }
    }
```

This is model:

```
@Entity
public class Member extends Model {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required(message = "This item is Required")
    public String name;

    @Email(message = "Please Fill in a message")
    public String mail;

    public String tel;

    public static Finder<Long, Member> find = new Finder<Long, Member>(Long.class, Member.class);

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ids = "{id:";
        for (Message m: messages) {
            ids += " " + m.id;
        }
        ids += "}";
        return ("[id:" + id + ", message:" + ids + ", name:" + name + ", mail:" + mail + ", tel:" + tel + "]");
    }

    public static Member findByName(String input) {
        return Member.find.where().eq("name", input).findList().get(0);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Message extends Model{

    @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Member member;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required(message = "This item is required.")
    public String name;

    @Required(message = "This item is required")
    public String message;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    public Date postdate;

    public static Finder<Long, Message> find = 
                                    new Finder<Long, Message>(Long.class, Message.class);


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("[id:" + id +", message:" + message +  ", mail:" + member.mail +", members:" + member + ", data:" + postdate + "]");
    }

    public static Message findByName(String input) {
        return Message.find.where().eq("name", input).findList().get(0);
    }


}
```

route is like this:

```
GET     /add                        controllers.Application.add()

POST    /create                     controllers.Application.create()

GET     /add2                       controllers.Application.add2()

POST    /create2                    controllers.Application.create2()
```

If I eliminate the select method from above code, it still works well.
So, I don't know the meaning of the method. I have already the brief explanation of the method on the site showing play's API. And they say that "Explicitly sets a comma delimited list of the properties to fetch on the 'main' entity bean, to load a partial object.". But I don't understand where a comma delimited list is because the return type here is List. And what are  'main' entity bean and a partial object?
If you need supplemental information, please ask of me.

Comment: Do you use JPA or Ebean?

Comment: Probably I use both.

Comment: I'd recommend to decide for one of them. Otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: Sorry, although my comprehension might be wrong, but please let me say.  Ebean includes JPA in the structure, doesn't it?